# 'so much too..' construction

Tags: sentence-construction, construction

I would like someone to explain the way the "**so much too**" construction works in sentences. What prepositions work after this construction? I made up these sentence and would like to know if they work:

- He was **so much too** angry **to** even look at him.
- I was **so much too** happy about it **that** I couldn't avoid announcing it.
- This story is **so much too** good **to** be true.
- The man was **so much too** stupid **as to** leave her along.

Edit: Since we can use "**too**" to mean '*to a higher degree than is desirable*' can we add "**so much**" to it to intensify it even more and use it as a comparative? I was actually comparing it to "**so much (so) that**":

- I was **so much** happy about it **(so) that** I couldn't avoid announcing it.

Comment: I don't think anyone could explain the way the "so much too" construction works, because it's ***not a valid construction in English***. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: Note that *He **was so stupid** as to lie* means that he ***did*** lie (***because*** he was very stupid), but *He **was much too stupid** to lie* means he ***didn't*** lie (because he was very stupid - presumably too stupid to think of lying even though it would have been a clever thing to do in the circumstances).